# Rails how to allways gsub column before save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to make gsub on my column before save or update.

Here is my controller:

```
        def dansk(text)
    self.text.gsub('å', '&aring;')
    self.text.gsub('Å', '&Aring;')
    self.text.gsub('æ', '&aelig;')
    self.text.gsub('Æ', '&AElig;')
    self.text.gsub('ø', '&oslash;')
    self.text.gsub('Ø', '&Oslash;')
    end

def update  

        @photographer = Photographer.find(params[:id])          
        @photographer.update_attributes(params[:photographer])
        @photographer.text = dansk(params[:photographer][:text])
            @photographer.text = dansk(params[:photographer][:name])


                       !@photographer.save                              
            flash[:notice] = "&nbsp;"
            render_action 'edit'            


    end
```

What are I am doing wrong and why are the text and name not being "gsubbed" ?

**UPDATE:**
My helper:

```
def convert_html_entities(text)
    text.gsub(/&aring;/,"å")
    text.gsub(/&aelig;/,"æ")
    text.gsub(/&oslash;/,"ø")   
    text.gsub(/&copy;/,"©")
    text = text.gsub(/["]/, '&quot;')       
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do this at the **Model** level (maybe put your dansk method in a module if you want to keep things DRY).

```
before_save :danskify

def danskify
  self.text = dansk(self.text) if text_changed?
  self.name = dansk(self.name) if name_changed?
end

def dansk(text)
  [['å', '&aring;'], ['Å', '&Aring;'], ['æ', '&aelig;'], ['Æ', '&AElig;'], ['ø', '&oslash;'], ['Ø', '&Oslash;']].each do |rule|
    text = text.gsub(rule[0], rule[1])
  end
end
```

In your controller, you'd only need:

```
def update  
  @photographer = Photographer.find(params[:id])          
  @photographer.update_attributes(params[:photographer])
  flash[:notice] = "&nbsp;" #weird message BTW
  render :edit  
end
```

Comment: Can I use an application helper in the model or the controller ?

Comment: If I were you, I'd create a separate module containing your dansk method and then include it in you ApplicationHelper and in the appropriate models.

Comment: When the model is saved it have replaced all the text with [["å", "å"], ["Å", "Å"], ["æ", "æ"], ["Æ", "Æ"], ["ø", "ø"], ["Ø", "Ø"]]

Comment: wow... don't understand, change the danks method as I just edited to see

Comment: I changed the dansk and it is now working. The only problem is when the edit form is rendered the name is not html escaped. I have tried to add the following to my edit action:   @photographer.name = raw(@photographer.name) but get the error: undefined method `raw' for... I am using simple_form_for..

Comment: Ok, curious to know what was the problem. You should add `:value =>  convert_html_entities(f.object.name)` within your form helper

Comment: I have created a new question for that problem. The first problem was your def dansk(text) it replaced all the text with  [['å', '&aring;'], ['Å', '&Aring;'], ['æ', '&aelig;'], ['Æ', '&AElig;'], ['ø', '&oslash;'], ['Ø', '&Oslash;']] I changed dansk(text) to use text.gsub().gsub()... etc.

Answer (score 2):

No offense, but your code doesn't make any sense. Is 'def dansk' in your controller. There are multiple problems.

**How to get it work**

1. In *dansk* it should be "text.gsub" not "self.text.gsub". *self* in that context is a reference to the controller itself.
2. Calling *text.gsub* a bunch of times won't do what you want. *gsub* returns a **new** string with the offending chars replaced, leaving the original string unchanged. So you're basically losing all those changes since you're only returning the final one. It should look like this

   ```
   def dansk(text)
     text.gsub('å', '&aring;').gsub('Å', '&Aring;')...
   end
   ```

or this (gsub! applies it's changes to the original string)

```
def dansk(text)
  text.gsub!('å', '&aring;')
  text.gsub!('Å', '&Aring;')
  ...
  text
end
```

**The best way**

This way, every time you call 'save' on a Photographer object, those chars you don't want will be replaced automatically.

```
model Photographer
  ...
  before_validation :dansk!
  ...

  private

  def dansk!
    self.text.gsub!('å', '&aring;')
    self.text.gsub!('Å', '&Aring;')
    ...
  end
end

@photographer = Photographer.find(params[:id])          
@photographer.update_attributes(params[:photographer])
@photographer.save
```

Comment: I removed my former comment. This works, but is just undry (the name should be changed as well) and not optimized. BTW no need to save after update_attributes.

Comment: the model don´t want to save when I write example the lette æ å ø

Answer (score 0):

Neglecting other strange issues with your code, you want the gsub!() method (note the exclamation mark). gsub!() modifies the String in place, while gsub() (no exclamation mark) returns a new String object.